# Do tokens created through Stellar map one-to-one?

Tags: xlm, token, assets, issuing, multi-sig

One more token question!

When creating a token using Stellar, as described in https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar/ - do the newly created tokens need to map one-to-one?

Ie. one XLM to one new token? Or can it be one XLM to N tokens. Or even, N XLM tokens to 1 token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

New tokens on Stellar are created through adding a trustline with a Change Trust operation. You can set up as many trustlines as you want so long as you fulfil the [minimum account balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html) (basically (2+x) * base reserve), and each trustline is affiliated with one issuer account ID; there is no one-to-one mapping between Stellar native currency and tokens.